# Plotting a heat map for a given function with changing parameters

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot a heat map for a function I have defined. Within my function, I have the value of `A` and the value of `p`, so in my heat map I want `A` and `p` to be my x and y axis. When I run my code, only a quarter of the heat map is plotted and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code and what I have been trying.

```
def funct_one(A, x, p):
    return np.log(abs((A/4) * (((p+1)**(p+1))/p**p) * ((p*x**(p-1)) - (p+1)*x**p))) 

def funct_two(A, x, p):
    n1 = 101
    n2 = 101
    var_l = 0
    for i in range(n1):
        x = log(A, x, p)
        var_l = var_l + funct_one(A, x, p)
        for j in range(n2):
            glob_l = var_l/n2
    return glob_l

A = np.linspace(0.1,4,50)
p = np.linspace(0.5,5,50)

# Filling heatmap
map = np.empty((A.size, p.size))
for i in range(A.size):
    for j in range(p.size):
        x=0.2
        map[i,j] = funct_two(A[i], x, p[j])
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
s = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, xlabel='A', ylabel='p')
im = s.imshow(map, extent=(A[0], A[-1], p[0], p[-1]),origin='lower')
fig.colorbar(im)
```

The heat map doesn't fill completely, only a quarter of it is filled and the rest is left blank. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I don't know whether this question is still relevant to you, but: could you tell us what `x = log(A, x, p)` is?

Comment: Stack overflow doesn’t allow me to delete this question but it turns out that the heat map was plotting the colour white as a value which gave me the illusion that the map wasn’t fully coloured in